# No module 'yum' on Python 3 on CentOS 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos7, rhel7

I'm trying to use the [yum Python package](http://yum.baseurl.org/api/yum/yum/__init__.html) in CentOS 7.

In **Python 2**: I can successfully `import yum`.

In **Python 3**: When I try to `import yum`, I encounter `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yum'`.

The exact same issue occurs with the [dnf Python package](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) after I install dnf.

Researching around the issue took me to CentOS 8, where `dnf` package does work on Python 3.
When trying to find `python3-dnf` package (or the equivalent one for `yum`) in CentOS 7.
Trying to install CentOS 8 packages on CentOS 7 only led me to conflicts and mismatches with required packages.

Also, trying to `pip3 install yum` does not find any package, and `pip3 install dnf` succeeds but importing gives the following warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dnf.py:15: UserWarning: The DNF Python API is not currently available via PyPI.

Please install it with your distro package manager (typically called
'python2-dnf' or 'python3-dnf'), and ensure that any virtual environments
needing the API are configured to be able to see the system site packages
directory.

  warnings.warn(warning_msg)
```

So, currently I can't find a way to interact natively with `yum`/`dnf` with Python code, running Python 3 on CentOS 7.

Answer (score 9):

My computer runs Fedora, and I have no access to a CentOS installation, but I think the information below is correct for it.

The `yum` and `dnf` modules you're using are not your everyday `pip` modules.  Instead, they are actually part of the `dnf` and `yum` rpms.

You can check that this way:

*Python2*

```
>>> import yum
>>> help(yum)
(...)
FILE
    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py

$ dnf -C repoquery --file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/__init__.py
yum-0:3.4.3-518.fc29.noarch
```

*Python3*

```
>>> import dnf
>>> help(dnf)
(...)
FILE
    /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py

$ dnf -C repoquery --file     /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py
python3-dnf-0:4.0.4-1.fc29.noarch
python3-dnf-0:4.2.5-5.fc29.noarch
```

If you check the `yum` and `dnf` files, you'll see that they are both `python3` scripts

```
$ head -1 /usr/bin/yum /usr/bin/dnf
==> /usr/bin/yum <==
#!/usr/bin/python3

==> /usr/bin/dnf <==
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

If you look at `yum` in detail, you'll see that it is actually a call to the `dnf` module.

So, the availability of the `yum` or `dnf` module for Python will depend on which version of the actual commands you have installed.

For `dnf`, you can try to install `python2-dnf` or `python3-dnf`.  I'm not sure that you can have them both at the same time, though.  I guess you can, since they have different names in `/usr/bin`.

For `yum`, my guess is that they provide the Python 2 library for backward compatibility, but they have probably not bothered moving it to Python 3, given it is obsoleted by `dnf`

Again, this is all true for my version of Fedora.  Your version of CentOS may get different results and package names, but the bottom line should be the same: Python2 lib only for `yum`; install different `dnf` packages for different Python version modules.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, but unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue in CentOS 7.

Comment: @OrB, I think my answer is actually "sorry, you can't".  `yum`/`dnf` are installed as system packages, so you have to work with what the system offers, and apparently on CentOS it only offers Python2 interfaces.  Why do you need specifically Python 3 bindings? what are you trying to accomplish?  And, also, how far are you willing to hack it to get it through?  You might be able to get through by crafting a `virtualenv` with proper requirements and adding the files from the python3-dnf package to it, for example.  But do you want to go there?

Comment: I specifically want Python 3 binding since Python 2 is going to retire in 15 days. It seems that you are right saying it's simply impossible, so currently I'm going to work around it by writing my code for Python 2 :(

Comment: @caxcaxcoatl I need Python 3 because Ansible is known to be very slow on systems with large number of file pointers when used on Python 2. But I can't use python 3 with Ansible to install packages on my CentOS 7 system with Yum and not Dnf. That's quite a puzzle I got.

Comment: @Gherman, why not?  How are you trying to do that?  Ansible has its own package modules, it shouldn't worry about Python 2 or 3 or which libs are available

Comment: @caxcaxcoatl It shouldn't? It does... I just tried to use standard Ansible yum module and it won't work with Python 3.

Comment: @Gherman, your issue is a bit off-topic for this question, I think you should open it on the DevOps SE site.  In any case, I think you can either use Ansible's `dnf` module (and some logic to decide which to use on the playbook), or, much better, use the generic `package` module, which should pick the right command automatically.  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/package_module.html

Comment: @caxcaxcoatl You asked "Why do you need specifically Python 3 bindings?". I gave you an example. Generally it's not uncommon to want a specific version of a platform/runtime for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @Gherman, ok, it makes sense.  I just want to double check you tried Python 3 + Ansible + the `package` module.  I'm not sure whether Ansible uses the libs or command calls, so it might be worth the try, as  you only mention the `yum` module.  And again, if that does not work, it would be a valid question for DevOps